# Redirect based on referrer domain

Tags: .htaccess

I noticed that I am getting a lot of hits from various adult oriented sites that are sent by some spam server, because they all come from the same domain. I would like to add redirect instructions to my .htaccess file, to send them elsewhere without them being able to even hit my index page.

The problem is that the subdomain of that referrer seem to be changing all the time.

37-115-112-240-broadband.kyivstar.net
178-137-94-155-lvv.broadband.kyivstar.net

I am OK to block entire ALL traffic from this server.

I was thinking doing something like this, but am not sure how to accommodate the dynamic subdomains.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://whatever\.com
RewriteRule .* http://www.anotherdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can relax your regex and have your rule like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} broadband\.kyivstar\.net 
RewriteRule ^ http://www.anotherdomain.com/? [R=301,L]
```